# Best method to determine current in ESR meter

Tags: design, current-measurement, measurement, esr

I've recently found the need for a ESR meter(My daughter and her boyfriend brought me 8 broken LED/LCD TVs and 6 have power problems).

I also decided to go all out and build a full blown ESR meter.  The foundation for the meter is going to be the STM32F373 which has 3 16bit Sigma Delta ADC which are capable of simultaneous differential conversion.  It also has DSP capabilities so I was going to use a DFT to determine impedance and go from there.

So I'll measure voltage across a test resistor, across the Cap under test and current.  I want to use both variable voltage and frequency.  I thought to use .2V to 1V for voltage and 100Hz to 25Khz for frequency.  The test signal will be generated using one of the internal DACs filtered to a sine wave and buffered(for voltage and current control, including constant current(Edit to make it obvious)).  I think I'll just output all this info via serial port and use a program to display and control.  I can always add a interface later.

Sorry for all the leading information but I wanted make sure the question could be answered.  With my brain though I've most likely forgotten something.

My question is under these circumstances which method of measuring current is better, using a shunt resistor or a current transformer.   I've looked at a large assortment of various types of meters and just can't make up my mind.

I have a couple of IN Amps, a large assortment of op-amps and passive components available to me.

Comment: The foundation for **any design** is your design **specification** and test method, not the parts.  An LCR meter uses a constant current source for sine wave at various frequencies to measure voltage and phase shift.

Comment: Fundamentally, the ESR is the quadrature component to the charging-current. Hence a precision ESR must sustain clean I and Q extraction.  How to specify that?

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 My DAC output buffering will allow a choice of constant voltage or constant current.  I thought I was clear in how I am testing with 2 voltage tests and a current test.  My problem is choosing the best way to test the current.

Comment: And please note, all 3 SD ADC can be triggered at the same time.  I was planning on first running a small test to determine zero crossing and then take 10 measurements per frequency.  I'll have choice of doing a single freq or a span.

Comment: Usually phase  and amplitude of output voltage with auto ranging sine current determines the mode of RLC then reactance in F or H  and resistance in Ohms.

Comment: Ok, I have the STM32F373 main board done.  Right now I'm testing DAC output filters for the higher frequency's.   As I'm using lookup tables for the sine output, at lower frequency's I'll just use a large number of samples with a simple 3 stage LP filter.  I'm thinking of using a AD812 as the output amp as it should have no problem with .2, .5, 1 and 1.5V out with decent current.  I may not be able to measure the ESR of pF caps, but just about anything else should be good.  Once I have that filter, I guess I'll just test which is better, the current transformer or shunt.  I'll report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay.

After testing both methods using various shunts(.01, .05(1%, .5%, no idea)  and CT's(4 hand wound and 2 commercial (small value burden and tried with both with no gain and gain))), I'm going to go with a shunt.  The CT's ended up having various phase errors that were in 1 case very non-linear(but that could have been my error, it was one of the home made ones).

The way I tested the them was:

1. Using a Function Generator set to 100Khz and then setting up a sweep from 1Khz to 100Khz with slow steps and .25 to 3vpp.
2. For a reference resistor I used a couple of old 1 and 220 ohm .5% mil-spec resistors (still on the reel) I picked up at a ham-fest years ago. Through hole, blue and lots of bands..:)
3. The best I could do for the DUT were a some 5% film caps 104J and 163J.  I was too lazy to make any inductors(The only ones I have are either low-Q crud or much better rf air core(I guess I could have taken one of the tank coils out of an amp, but that would have been overkill plus work), neither of which I thought would be helpful here)

Then I would observe the wave forms using my VDS1022(25Mhz) (I used a Kikusui 5060(60Mhz) to confirm that the DSO traces at least resembled reality) Then a screen cap was made.

After comparing them the shunts were all in line, meaning no surprises.  The CT's were not bad, meaning they were fairly consistent within a device, but when compared to each other or the shunts, there was differences(Would the term jitter also apply here??).

Since I'm easily able to control by excitation and gain, the shunts just make it much easier without having to play follow the leader trying to tune a CT circuit or apply corrections in software.

Please note, the final application will end up being a LCR/ESR meter.  I doubt I'll ever go over 50V or 1A.  On the other hand I think if your dealing with trying to measure mains the inaccuracies of a CT really do not matter.  The simple fact is that the chance of your voltage/current wave form being nicely symmetrical, of whatever shape, is so close to 0 as not to matter, meaning a little bouncing around really will not affect the measurements.  And using a CT or Rogowski coil makes it much easier to measure your 120V+ at whatever current.